# ¿Como insertar en una tabla de SQL server un campo que no es auto-incrementado?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una tabla que tiene un campo "id" pero no esta definida como auto-incrementado dentro de la BD, Existe la posibilidad de que al insertarle un registro indicar que el "id" va a se un campo auto-incrementado usando C#.

Comment: Puedieras explicar un poco mas en cuanto al porqué prefieras insertar el `id` en C# y en cuanto a como planeas hacerlo. No sería mejor que modificaras la tabla para fuera auto incrementado?

Comment: Es que no tengo acceso a la base de datos mas que por conexion y no puedo hacerle modificaciones mas que insertar y consultar.

Comment: string insertEncontrada = "INSERT INTO Seguimiento(id_seguimiento, sistema, ubicacion, fecha) VALUES(auto_increment, sistema, ubicacion, CONVERT(DATETIME, fecha, 102))"; en donde uso un SqlCommand para pasar los datos y ejecutar el query pero no tengo idea de como hacerle para el campo que quiero que sea autoincrementado.

Comment: Pues alguien debe tener acceso, no?  No le puedes pedir a ese alguien que te arregle la tabla?

Comment: @Alberto Rojas Es mejor cambiar la estructura de la tabla. Sql Server garantizaría la atomicidad de la inserción sin tener que recurir a códigos que intentan reinventar la rueda. ¿Sería posible eso?

Comment: Gracias por el tip a ambos ya recurri a los de DBA para el cambio a la estructura de la tabla y ya pude resolver el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Se debería calcular obteniendo el último valor y luego sumando 1:

```
INSERT INTO Tabla
(Id, Valor)
VALUES((SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM Tabla), 'Descripción del campo' )
```

Comment: Esto es peligroso en casos de concurrencia ademas que segun el tamaño de la tabla, puede afectar el tiempo de ejecucion.

Comment: Es correcto, aunque se podría iniciar una transacción del lado del CodeBehind, ejecutar el INSERT en base de datos y completar la transacción en el CodeBehind

Comment: Aun eso tiene peligros.  2 transacciones concurrentes pueden leer el mismo valor para `MAX(Id)`. Uno de los insert trataria de insertar un duplicado.

Comment: Al iniciar una transacción se bloquea la tabla y realiza el cálculo del último Id de forma adecuada, se completa la transacción y se libera la tabla para otras que transacciones realicen el mismo proceso.

Comment: Es correcto, aunque todo puede depender del objetivo de la solución que se requiere implementar. En este caso podría ser mayor el trabajo para implementar una solución a la pregunta realizada que modificar el campo y hacerlo auto incrementable.

Comment: Es mejor cambiar la estructura de la tabla. Sql Server garantizaría la atomicidad de la inserción sin tener que recurir a códigos que intentan reinventar la rueda.